# How to represent a precondition in uml

Tags: uml

Imagine you have 2 use case A and B.

To execute case B, A has to be already done ( A is precondition of B), but when you execute A you dont need  to execute B

Like this?

User -> A

User -> B -> include A

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.batimes.com/articles/use-case-preconditions-a-best-kept-secret.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preconditions in UML are represented with a [constraint](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/constraint.html). You are allowed to express it in natural language.

Nevertheless, an UML use case diagram intends to give an overview of the main objectives/intents that an actor can achieve with the system under consideration.  And your preconditions are a level of detail that should rather belong to the specification of the use case (be it expressed with an UML activity diagram or textual narratives like [Cockburn](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Basic+use+case+template)'s ones).

Also the constraint is ambiguous: Is it a constraint linked to the state of the system (i.e. A should be executed at least once before B) ? Or is it a sequencing (i.e. Every single time you want to execute B you first have to go over A) ?  In the latter case, you could consider B with a larger scope, so that it includes A and show this [include-relationship](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-include.html) in the diagram.

Comment: Thenk you, its like your second case, like firt you need to "log in" and then you can "send text" or "put profule pic". I understand with what you have said that it is with include- relationship

Comment: Customers don't usually buy a system to "log in". This is of no value to the user. A constraint "user must be logged in" or rather adding a logged in user actor (child of unregistered user actor) would be preferable. See [this other question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/349597/93338).

Answer (score 0):

Two alternative thoughts on this, for a Use Case diagram or description.

If A is an optional part of Use Case B, use an "Extend" relationship between them. In this case, that is the purpose of that relationship.

If A may be initiated outside of Use Case B, then I would use a "Dependency" relationship between them. You might need to add an appropriate label describing the nature of the dependency

In some cases, you might be best adding a higher-level use case that includes B and is extended by A. This would be a situation where A and B are only related by a process decision, not because they are inherently related. This helps differentiate between the inherent complexity and the accidental/incidental complexity.

Comment: You seem to start functional decomposition with that approach. No good. The OP is asking about constraints.